# Update table but skipping some rows with specific condition

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `body_scan` that looks like this:

```
body_no  tag
--------------------
1        noscan
2        noscan
3        missing
4        noscan
5        missing
```

I also have a list that I can load into a temp table like so

```
tag_no
------
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

What I need to be able to do is to update the `body_scan` table with the tag numbers in the temporary table.

You will notice that there are only 3 tags in the temp table but 5 in the body_scan table. I need to update the tag value "noscan" with values from the temp table and leave the missing as they are..

The order of the tags in the temporary table is the same as the order of `body_no` from the `body_scan` table.

So yes, I did consider the `row_number()` function. But I'm just not 100% sure how to define the join correctly..

How do I achieve this please?

The desired result is :

```
body_no  tag
-------------------
1        aaa
2        bbb
3        missing
4        ccc
5        missing
```

Comment: can you not add row number to tag_no?

Comment: Tables have no order. When populating the "temp table", you need to assign the order in a seperate field. If you assume that rows will always return in the same order without and`order by`, you're going to have problems.

Comment: sorry, no. I receive the file that way.. so all I can do is load the tags into a temp table.. updating the body_scan table is the tricky bit.  All I can do is use row_number to generate a row number on the temp table.. but that won't always match on the join to the body_scan table.. hence the need for this question in the first place!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid wont a row_number over(order by (select 1000)) as rowid achieve the same? Ordering by the rowid column should get the desired result right? Keeping the tag file in the order that was received?

Comment: They are most certainly in order in a file but they aren't in a table. So you need to add an `identity` field to your temp table to record that order, otherwise that information is lost. When you use `row_number()` it still needs to use an order but again it's arbitrary and there is _no_ guarantee that it will be the same as what was in the file. It probably will 95% of the time but do you really want to bake a known bug into your code?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for pointing this out.. I see your point and I think I can easily implement an identity field when bulk loading the file into a table and preserve the order in which it was read.. can you help joining to the other table please?

Comment: OK so that is now just a matter of using `row_number()` or `rank()` against `body_scan`, but writing the correct expression so that it skips the _missing_ records.... That's the concept but I can't think of how to do it right at this moment - lets see if someone beats me to it

Comment: And what happens when the number of rows with "noscan" exceeds the number of rows in the other table?

Comment: @SMor that's fine.. it's sequential.. once the tag_no in the temp table runs out.. we are done.. no more processing required.. I.E. leave the noscan as is in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to preserve the *input file* order of data by adding an `identity` field to the `temp_table` (note that some ETL tools insert data in parallel and that messes things up so you might even need to add this column to the file)

Once you've done that, you need to generate a key in body_scan that you can join to. This is simply `ROW_NUMBER()` over the existing table, excluding the missing rows

This returns the row and what it should be matched to in `temp_table`

```
SELECT 
body_no,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY body_no) RN
FROM body_scan
WHERE tag<> 'missing';
```

This joins in the temp table (assumes your ordinal column is called RowID)

```
SELECT T1.body_no, T1.tag, T1.RN, T2.tag_no
FROM
(
SELECT 
body_no,tag,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY body_no) RN
FROM body_scan
WHERE tag<> 'missing'
) T1
INNER JOIN
temp_table T2 
ON T1.RN=T2.RowID;
```

This updates it back to the table:

```
UPDATE TGT
SET tag=SRC.tag_no
FROM body_scan TGT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT T1.body_no, T2.tag_no
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    body_no,tag,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY body_no) RN
    FROM body_scan
    WHERE tag<> 'missing'
    ) T1
    INNER JOIN
    temp_table T2 
    ON T1.RN=T2.RowID 
) SRC
ON SRC.body_no=TGT.body_no;
```

(There's half a dozen ways to write that final statement but I prefer this way as you can see the dataset you're updating from in the subselect)

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand your explanation and command discussion. I workout(in SQL 2012) to achieve your OUTPUT table. As,

```
update a
set a.tag = t.tag
from (
 select m.*, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by m.tag order by m.rn)trn from(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by (select null) order by (select null)) rn from body_scan --set order what the order of actual table's order
 ) m --set row number for noscan rows
) a
join(
 select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) rn from #temp --set order what the order of actual table order
) t
on a.trn = t.rn and a.tag <> 'missing' -- join to noscan rows using row numbers
```

OUTPUT:

```
body_no   tag
--------------
   1      aaa
   2      bbb
   3      missing
   4      ccc
   5      missing
```

Comment: Thank you.. this worked as well.. but unfortunately.. I can only accept one answer

Comment: @Harry.. Were you used my query and get expected table..?